# Is there graphical editor for mac supporting non linear distortions (stretch)?

Tags: vector, shapes, transform, distort

I am a software developer facing a rare need to create single PNG icon. It should be a horizontal gradient (white to transparent) rectangle stretched to the right - so that right edge of the rectange will become quadratic bezier curve. The gradient should also be stetched.

I thought this is very simple to do but I just spend a day on it without any progress. I haven't found graphical editor that would support non-linear (non-affine) transformation of shapes.

I would be very gratefull for any help.

EDIT: Here is sketch of what is my goal:

[image]

Comment: After more googling I and reading it looks like I need a vector editor for mac with bend/warp tool. Unfortunatelly, the only one I have found so far is extremly expensive. Especially when I need it only for one use.

Comment: Can you give an illustration of what you're trying to create?

Comment: To add to @ZachSaucier’s comment: Please do your best to sketch what you’re after and add it to your question. Maybe someone here will help create it?

Comment: @ZachSaucier There it is.

Comment: @MarcEdwards Please see my edit

Comment: Illustrator can create such a blend between objects and colors.

Comment: @Jongware How? I installed trial version of Inlustrator and trying to acheave it by aplying envelope distort (object->envelope distort->make with mesh) on rectangle with gradient but that does not produce what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Illustrator:

[image: blend steps]

1. Draw a rectangle with a certain color.
2. Draw an ellipse behind it, with the same color but with transparency set to 0%.
3. Select both and choose Object > Blend > Make.
4. The default setting seems to be a bit tight. With the object still selected, choose Object > Blend > Blend Options.
5. Switch Preview on to see what you are doing. Select "Specified Steps" - you will see the default value "1" appear - and enter a sufficiently high number. My sample image below uses 30 for clarity; you may want a higher number.
6. Select the Artboard tool (or press Shift+O) and resize the artboard to the size of your object (newer versions of Illustrator should have a shortcut for this under the Object menu).
7. Choose File > Save for Web & Devices to export a PNG.

Comment: Perfect answer, exactly what I need. Thank you